# Server result to webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, callback

I am trying to simply write out some data to my webpage as a result of a callback. Everything works up until the point where I need to output the result of the callback.

**Client-side:**

```
function toServer(data) {
    var dataPackage = data + "~";
    jQuery('form').each(function () {
        document.getElementById('payload').value = JSON.stringify({ sendData: dataPackage });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: window.location.href.toString(),
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                //this does not work because it just puts an entire source code copy of my site in there instead...
                //document.getElementById('searchResults').value = result
                console.log("callback compelete");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("callback Error");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Server-Side: (on page load)**

```
            //holds actions from page
            string payload = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["payload"] ?? String.Empty;

            // See if there were hidden requests (callbacks)
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(payload))
            {
                string temp_AggregationId = CurrentMode.Aggregation;
                string[] temp_AggregationList = temp_AggregationId.Split(' ');
                Perform_Aggregation_Search(temp_AggregationList, true, Tracer);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchResultsJSON"] = "";
            }
```

The rest of the server-side code works properly and just handles the parsing of the incoming and performs a search of the db and then parses the search results into a JSON obj.

Currently, the only way the json obj gets written to the page is if I call it without the callback (just call it on page load). Also, in firebug, it looks like the entire page source is posting back as the 'result' of the callback. I do see my json result within the posted back 'result' but it also contains the entire page HTML.

Moreover, I can't seem to get the result to post to the page which is the whole point. Actually, I could get the result to post to the page by simply uncommenting that bit in the client side code but it posts a copy of my site and not the actual result I thought I created...

What am I missing? How do you explicitly state in the C# code what is returned to the JS callback as 'result'?

Answer (score 0):

You get the entire page because you're making a request to an ASP.NET page. In fact, you're requesting the vary same page you're viewing. The server is returning what it would return if you were submitting a form.

To get JSON data, you need to create a web method to handle your request. Read [this article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Make-AJAX-Call-to-ASP.Net-Server-Side-Web-service-method-using-jQuery.aspx), it will help you. It shows you how to return simple text, but you can return JSON too. Information on this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Finally, to make sure jQuery is parsing the server response as JSON, change your request and indicate it explicitly:

```
function toServer(data) {
    var dataPackage = data + "~";
    jQuery('form').each(function () {
        document.getElementById('payload').value = JSON.stringify({ sendData: dataPackage });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: window.location.href.toString(),
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                //this does not work because it just puts an entire source code copy of my site in there instead...
                //document.getElementById('searchResults').value = result
                console.log("callback compelete");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("callback Error");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I attempted to implement the articles example but my new public method of processCallback is never called on the callback. I suspect this is to do with how 'buried' my class is that renders the page from the page's codebehind file, thus the url.com/processCallback DNE. Is that the case or did I do something else incorrectly?